# Сборка плагина для VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, плагин

Добрый день,

занялся созданием плагина под вижуалку, описал его работу, в дебаге запускал, видел, как он выглядит в VS, и казалось бы всё прекрасно, да вот сейчас не знаю что дальше. Как мне его собрать и установить под свою вижуалку. Посёрфив, понял, что в итоге я получу файл .vsix, который потом должен буду установить. Так как же это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось всё весьма банально, в Visual Studio есть для этого все инструменты, а более подробно про это рассказывает вот эта [статья](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241.aspx)